# Switching UIViewControllers programmatically on button click

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have 2 viewcontrollers. The starting/first one is made through storyboard while the other one programmatically. The second one contains a toolbar and a table. I have made a button in the second one, which when is clicked, the app should return to the main view controller. The button is placed in a row of the tableview with a custom cell style (imageCellCell), which has its own class. I have tried this so far but I get the following error:

**imageCellCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imageCellCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *homebtn;



@end
```

**imageCellCell.m**

```
#import "imageCellCell.h"

@implementation imageCellCell

@synthesize view;
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;
@synthesize prodimage;
@synthesize thumbsup;
@synthesize label3;
@synthesize basket;
@synthesize home;
@synthesize homebtn;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [self addSubview:view];

        // initiate home button       
        homebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,0, 30, 30)];

        [homebtn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
        [homebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [homebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [view addSubview:homebtn];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**secondviewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondviewcontroller.h : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>
{ NSArray* data;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabbar;


-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

**secondviewcontroller.m**

```
#import "secondviewcontroller.h"
#import "imageCellCell.h"


@interface secondviewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation secondviewcontroller
@synthesize tableview;
@synthesize tabbar;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {





NSString *CellIdentifier;
NSString *CellIdentifierimg;

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [[imageCellCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierimg];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    }





    if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    }

    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {

            imageCellCell *firstRowCell = (imageCellCell *)cell;


            firstRowCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;


        }
        case 1:
        {

                cell.textLabel.text = @"Detailed Score";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;

        }



-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"maincontroller"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];    
}


@end
```

**Error:**

```
   014-07-09 14:23:16.022 EcoUI[1046:f803] -[imageCellCell clickButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6888bd0
    2014-07-09 14:23:16.026 EcoUI[1046:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[imageCellCell clickButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6888bd0'
```

Updated code in **imageCellCell.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"


     SecondViewController *controltarg = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
            [homebtn addTarget:controltarg action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `imageCellCell.m` file for button selector target you have assigned `self`, which means it will look into imageCellCell.m file for the selector method and it is not there.

Hence it giving error, as unrecognized selector.

Comment: You are right. I included the targ of secondviewcontroller in imageCellCell, but it still won't switch view controller. it will give as output (lldb)

Comment: Done included the new lines below

Comment: I tried to create a new object of the class the buttons method exists. What is the right way to set the target to the other class?

Comment: But my button initialization is located in a different class

Answer (score 0):

Button you have it in tableview cell and adding action for that button there. But you giving implementation for button action in your view controller .Thats why u getting that error. Try to use delegate.